# Python client connecting to SAML webserver with private certification path

Tags: python, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, user-agent, bearer-token

I wish to connect to an internal webserver/webapp that offers services behind TLS and uses SAML2 for authentication within our organisation. This SSO works with my browser. I want to do this in >Python3.7 but if I got it working in >Go1.15 that would do. I have searched for examples but get whiteout with IDP and SP and not on how to be a user agent and collect and pass on a bearer assertion.

Comment: Logging into the app and copying the session cookie and providing that in, say, `curl` I can get what I want but I'd like a programmatic way to do that so that I could write client side Python applications that use the webservice and also use CEF and Selenium, to test my webserver.